# Is the game tree of any impartial game well-founded? Why or why not?

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I'm trying to understand why the [game tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_tree) of any [impartial game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impartial_game#:%7E:text=In%20combinatorial%20game%20theory%2C%20an,that%20player%201%20goes%20first.) (even transfinite, like transfinite Nim) must be [well-founded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-founded_relation) under the "is reachable from" relation (say, if the position $G'$ is reachable from $G$ after some moves, then $G'\mathcal R G$). Why must every non-empty set of positions of an impartial game have some minimal elements? Why can't there be infinite descending chains of game positions in such a non-empty set?

Comment: If the game must terminate, then there cannot be an infinite chain of positions $x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots$ such that $x_1$ is reachable from $x_0$ and $x_2$ is reachable from $x_1$ and so on.  If there were, then there would be endless games (going through $x_0$ and then through $x_1$ and so on).

Comment: But the winning strategy may not involve going through all those positions. Maybe the definition of impartial games says that "every possible game has to terminate"?

Comment: What is your definition of "impartial game"?  Often it is simply taken as part of the definition that it is well-founded.

Comment: Right, as @EricWofsey said.... it's generally not just optimum play that must terminate, but every possible game.

Answer (score 2):

The Wikipedia article on impartial games states that there must be a finite number of positions, so an infinite descending chain of different positions is not possible.  It does not specify that there be no cycles, so one could have a game that returned to a position seen earlier.  The Wikipedia article on the [Sprague-Grundy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem) does specify that all impartial games must end, so they are well-founded.  In the early definition of a game in Winning Ways they say that games must end, but admit that some of the games they consider do not meet all the rules.  In fact, they discuss in passing the game On, which has just one move from the starting position back to the starting position.

You need to look carefully at the definition you are using of an impartial game to see if they must be well founded or not.

Comment: If we consider transfinite impartial games like transfinite Nim there may be an infinite number of positions. But still the "the game must terminate" condition must hold. How does it follow from "the game must terminate" condition that the game tree is well-founded? As far as I understand, it just implies that the entire game tree has a minimal element (say, the empty game in case of Nim) but not that *every* non-empty subset has minimal elements.

Comment: @S.D.:  If the whole tree has a minimal element and there are no cycles then any subset has at least one minimal element.  Just follow the tree downwards.  If you don't come to the overall minimal element, you will come to one that has no predecessor in your set.